# Query joining the same table 3 times

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a query that works perfectly in phpMyAdmin, however when I try to call it in a .php file I get the following error.

```
Undefined variable: mothers_name in C:\wamp\www\Family_Tree\showfamily.php on line 56
```

My code is:

```
$select_query = "SELECT a.id, CONCAT( a.surname,  ', ', a.first_names ) AS child_name, " . 
"CONCAT( b.surname,  ', ', b.first_names ) AS mothers_name, " .
"CONCAT( c.surname, ', ', c.first_names ) AS fathers_name " .
"FROM family_members a " .
"INNER JOIN family_members b ON a.mother_id = b.id " .
"INNER JOIN family_members c ON a.father_id = c.id" .
"WHERE a.id = " . $user_id;
```

Am I getting this error because the tables "a","b" and "c" and the fields "mother_id" and "father_id" doesn't exist until the SQL is called through the mysql_query($select_query) function.

The code before line 56 looks up, returns and displays the results as they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
..._id = c.id" .               // <-- you forgot a space, results in c.idWHERE
"WHERE a.id = " . $user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this all much easier if you step back from the java style line breaking and attack it thusly. There's no need in PHP for splitting it up, and the extra punctuation makes is easier to make a mistake.

```
$select_query = 
"SELECT 
     a.id, 
     CONCAT( a.surname, ', ', a.first_names ) AS child_name, 
     CONCAT( b.surname, ', ', b.first_names ) AS mothers_name,
     CONCAT( c.surname, ', ', c.first_names ) AS fathers_name 
FROM family_members a 
INNER JOIN family_members b ON a.mother_id = b.id 
INNER JOIN family_members c ON a.father_id = c.id
WHERE a.id = " . $user_id;
```

This will let you use the very handy debugging tool of:

```
echo "[pre]" . $query . "[/pre]";
```

With the [ & ] actually being < & >. Sorry, new to SO.

THEN, you'll be able to copy/paste the actual query from your browser window into phpMyAdmin, and run that query and see if they actually are identical.